# Assigning javascript object to new object as copy

Tags: node.js, object, clone, lodash, javascript-objects

I have this array of object `obj.arr` in javascript.
I assigned it to a new object.

```
var obj_arr_new = obj.arr;
```

The problem is that when I modify `obj_arr_new`, `obj.arr` gets modified as well. I do not want that. How can I make `obj_arr_new` to be a copy of `obj.arr` and when I modify `obj_arr_new`, `obj.arr` is untouched?

I am using node.js v6. I am open to using any node.js module. Someone told me lodash can do the job. An answer using lodash would be helpful.

Comment: Did you do any research? There are plenty of questions about this already, and the lodash documentation is online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I did but there were a few methods in lodash which seems to fit the bill but I don't know exactly which one. Sorry, I'm rather slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lodash indeed has a `_.cloneDeep(value)` for this purpose.

```
var obj_arr_new = _.cloneDeep(obj.arr);
```

It will recursively clone "arrays, array buffers, booleans, date objects, maps, numbers, Object objects, regexes, sets, strings, symbols, and typed arrays" so that modifying bits of the clone doesn't affect the original, or vice versa.

[Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#cloneDeep)

Answer (score 1):

I tend to create a copy by using:

```
var copiedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject));
```

This only works for JSONable objects, but if you're dealing with strings, arrays etc then its fine, i.e not if you have functions as children of the object you're copying.